# syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting end — my code is missing an 'end' and I cannot figure out why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

## Error

[image: Error image]

Error in text:

```
D:/Projects/Web/RoR/ecommerce/app/controllers/search_controller.rb:46: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting end
```

As can be seen from the screenshot, the program is expecting (I think) an 'end' after the last line; at the very least, adding an extra 'end' removes the error message.

However, I just don't understand why. More shouldn't be necessary. Am I missing the obvious here?

It hurts me to put such a question here, but I'm about to tear my hair out.

## Code

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def search
    all_books = Book.all
    all_authors = Author.all
    all_genres = Genre.all
    @filtered_books = []

    # perform the search 
    params[:search_items].split(',').each do |token|

      token = token.downcase.strip

      unless token.empty? do
        # look in books
        all_books.each do |book|
          if book.title.downcase.include?(token) then
            @filtered_books << book
          end
        end

        # look in authors
        all_authors.each do |author|
          if author.full_name.downcase.include?(token) then
            @filtered_books << author.books
          end
        end

        # look in genres
        all_genres.each do |genre|
          if genre.name.downcase.include?(token) then
            @filtered_books << genre.books
          end
        end
      end # end for unless do
    end # end for params do
    
    # remove duplicates
    @filtered_books = @filtered_books.uniq
    render plain: @filtered_books
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

## Attempted Solutions

I installed a Ruby linter VS Code extension, and it tells me the same thing as the error message on-screen, but following its advice leaves me with 2 `end`s on the same "indentation level":

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def search
    all_books = Book.all
    all_authors = Author.all
    all_genres = Genre.all
    @filtered_books = []

    # perform the search 
    params[:search_items].split(',').each do |token|

      token = token.downcase.strip

      unless token.empty? do
        # look in books
        all_books.each do |book|
          if book.title.downcase.include?(token) then
            @filtered_books << book
          end
        end

        # look in authors
        all_authors.each do |author|
          if author.full_name.downcase.include?(token) then
            @filtered_books << author.books
          end
        end

        # look in genres
        all_genres.each do |genre|
          if genre.name.downcase.include?(token) then
            @filtered_books << genre.books
          end
        end
      end # end for unless do??
      end # end for params do??
    end
    # remove duplicates
    @filtered_books = @filtered_books.uniq
    render plain: @filtered_books
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

I tried putting the "fixed" code (by the linter) through a beautifier in hopes I wasn't seeing something, but it leaves a mess:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
        def search
        all_books = Book.all
        all_authors = Author.all
        all_genres = Genre.all
        @filtered_books = []
                # perform the search 
        params[:search_items].split(',').each do |token|
                        token = token.downcase.strip
                        unless token.empty? do
                # look in books
                all_books.each do |book|
                    if book.title.downcase.include?(token) then
                        @filtered_books << book
                    end
                end
                                # look in authors
                all_authors.each do |author|
                    if author.full_name.downcase.include?(token) then
                        @filtered_books << author.books
                    end
                end
                                # look in genres
                all_genres.each do |genre|
                    if genre.name.downcase.include?(token) then
                        @filtered_books << genre.books
                    end
                end
            end # end for unless do??
        end # end for params do??
    end
    # remove duplicates
    @filtered_books = @filtered_books.uniq
    render plain: @filtered_books
end
def show
end
end
```

Just what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `unless` with a `do` and Ruby's expecting an `end` to each `do`. That's also not the correct syntax of an `unless` statement.

Instead of

```
unless token.empty? do
```

write

```
unless token.empty?
```

Also, you shouldn't use [**then** in if statements](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-then).

Comment: Didn't I close the `unless`'s `do` with an `end`? I'll remove the `do` though and see if it takes (in the morning).

Comment: The `do` keyword isn't part of `unless`'s syntax

Comment: @verified_tinker: "Didn't I close the unless's do with an end?" – `unless` doesn't have a `do`. The consequence is separated from the condition with a `then`, not a `do`. (Or an expression separator such as `;` or newline.) The `do` starts a block passed to `token.empty?`, so you need *two* `end`s, one for the `unless` and one for the block.